# Celery beat not sending tasks with chrontab set to minute, hour

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to execute a task that sends an email at a specified hour and minute everyday. I'm on Python 3.7 and using the latest version of celery with a RedisBeat Scheduler and Redis for the broker and backend.

The tasks are recognised on celery beat when running but when the time comes to execute, nothing happens and it keeps repeating the Synchronising schedule and waking up print statements.

Here's the task.py file

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:16379/0"
CELERY_BACKEND_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:16379/0"

celery = Celery("tasks", broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL, backed=CELERY_BACKEND_URL)
celery.conf.update(
    CELERY_REDIS_SCHEDULER_URL='redis://127.0.0.1:16379/0',
    CELERY_TIMEZONE='UTC',
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True,
    CELERYBEAT_MAX_LOOP_INTERVAL=30

scheduler = RedisScheduler(app=celery)
```

The schedule digest task

```
def schedule_digest(email, hour, minute):
    
    scheduler.add(**{
        "name": "digest-" + email,
        "task": "lib.tasks.send_digest_email",
        "kwargs": {"to_address": email },
        "schedule": crontab(minute=minute, hour=hour)
    })
```

Celery beat log - In here I've set a task to get executed at 17:04 and as 17:04 passes, there's no execution of the task.

```
LocalTime -> 2022-06-14 17:03:06
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://127.0.0.1:16379/0
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> redisbeat.scheduler.RedisScheduler
    . db -> redis://127.0.0.1:16379/0, key -> celery:beat:order_tasks     
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> 30.00 seconds (30s)
[2022-06-14 17:03:06,359: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2022-06-14 17:03:06,359: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2022-06-14 17:03:06,454: INFO/MainProcess] Current schedule:
task: lib.tasks.send_digest_email; each: <crontab: 32 16 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
task: lib.tasks.send_digest_email; each: <crontab: 4 17 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
[2022-06-14 17:03:06,455: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->30.00 seconds
[2022-06-14 17:03:06,457: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 30.00 seconds.
[2022-06-14 17:03:36,471: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2022-06-14 17:03:36,476: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 30.00 seconds.
[2022-06-14 17:04:06,494: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 30.00 seconds.
[2022-06-14 17:04:36,501: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 30.00 seconds.
```

I start the worker and beat with

```
celery -A lib.tasks.celery worker -l info -P gevent
celery -A lib.tasks.celery beat -S redisbeat.RedisScheduler --loglevel=debug
```

If I change the schedule in the send_digest task to `"schedule": crontab(minute='*/10')` it works fine executing every 10 minutes but it's the hour and minute that's getting ignored.

I'd appreciate any advice on where I'm going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Try to run the worker, just for testing purposes, without -`P gevent`. And see if it runs any of the tasks. Also, make tasks being scheduled to run more frequently (every 10 minutes) so that you can debug easier.

Comment: @DejanLekic I got it running without `-P gevent` but the task still isn't sending. I changed schedule to `"schedule": crontab(minute='*/10')` and it works. The beat finds it and then sends it `[2022-06-15 12:20:00,006: INFO/MainProcess] add task entry: digest-email to publisher
[2022-06-15 12:20:00,071: DEBUG/MainProcess] lib.tasks.send_digest_email sent. id->601ae86e-a804-43b3-8a1e-b5cc8449054f`. Could it be the way I'm setting the crontab?

Comment: Could you please give us output of the beat. Did it actually trigger task at 17:04 ? Also keep in mind that your beat may run on remote machine which is in different time-zone!

Comment: I figured out the issue, it was more so on my part than celery. As you mentioned the beat could be running on a different timezone, it was in fact using UTC and when I had scheduled tasks at UTC time, it worked as expected. Thanks @DejanLekic.

Comment: Deleting the local celery-beat-scheduler file and restarting seemed to work in my case. It was stuck in the waking up too.